# Is it possible to check what version of files (from dependent project) the jar of project (foo) use ?

Tags: java, ant, jar, build

I'm a bit confused , i have a few projects on remote server. There I have a jar created by ant , that project(foo) which is convert to jar , have many other project added (they source path )as dependencies.I made some changes in projects and updated them on server , any change wasn't in project (foo) but in it dependencies. After that I rebuild project (foo) with ant . But jar (foo) probably doesn't use changes which I made . Is it  possible to check what version of files (from dependent project) the jar of project (foo) use ? And how to make jar of project (foo) use changes?

Comment: Rebuilding _foo_ project is probably not enough to ensure that it is using your modified dependencies. You have to be sure that your are refering to right version of dependencies jars in the classpath of _foo_ project at **runtime**. Are you sure of that ?

Comment: Thanks , that's what was wrong , after correcting it start working fine :D